# Customizing Calcite's Sql parser

Tags: apache-calcite, sql-parser

I am trying to use Apache Calcite's SqlParser to get entity level lineage for my views written in Hive and Impala.  However, the parser throws an exception for the following cases.

```
SELECT emp.1ab FROM emp -- Column name begins with numeric

org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered ".1" at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "AS" ...

SELECT PERIOD from emp -- column name is a key word (period)

Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "period from" at line 1, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    "ALL" ...
```

This is my SqlParser config.

```
SqlParser.Config config = SqlParser
                .configBuilder()
                .setConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.LENIENT)
                .build();
```

Is there any other config setting available to customize the parser to suit my needs.  All these queries are valid in Hive.

Comment: Are you able to change your input queries to quote column names?

Comment: Not really -  I am fetching the view definitions from the Hive Metastore, so dont have a lot of control.